# Prove $a + b$ is unique

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the sake of simplicity, let $a$ and $b$ be natural numbers. Prove that there exists exactly one element in the Natural numbers, call this number $c$, such that $a+b=c$.

Comment: What is the underlying set of axioms that we are talking about? :)

Comment: This question is meaningless until you tell us the assumptions and the definitions.

Comment: How is addition defined, and what properties of addition are we allowed to assume (commutative? associative? has a unique identity - or is this to be proved? etc)? And is subtraction already defined?

Comment: @MarkBennet it would be sufficient if we were given that addition is a binary operation at all

Comment: Still you should say what it means *precisely* for a number to be $a+b$ : the question does not strike me as a "tell me the definition", but as a "prove this property about this definition".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed

Answer (score 3):

This answer will make use of Peano's axioms for the definition of the natural numbers and addition.

We proceed by induction on $b$.

**Base Case**

Suppose $b = 0$ and that $a+b=c$ and $a+b=c'$. Then $c = a+b = a+0 = a$ and $c' = a+b = a+0 = a$. Since $c = a$ and $c' = a$, then $c = c'$.

**Inductive Step**
Assume that for $b = k$, the result is true, i.e., $a+k$ has a unique value which we'll call $c$. We want to prove the result is true for $b = s(k)$, i.e. that $a+s(k)$ has a unique value. Suppose that there exists $d$ and $d'$ such that $d = a+s(k)$ and $d' = a+s(k)$. Then,
$$d = a+s(k) = s(a+k) = s(c)$$
and
$$d' = a+s(k) = s(a+k) = s(c).$$

Since $d = s(c)$ and $d'=s(c)$, then $d = d'$, thus completing the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms). This, more or less, is the usual way we define the natural numbers, so I'm going to use these. For each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ we define a "successor" $S(n),$ and we assume at the outset that $S(m)=S(n)$ if and only if $m=n$ (that's axiom 7 in the linked-to list).

Now, what is $a+b?$ Skipping technical details, we have by definition
$$a+b = \underbrace{S(S(S(\ldots S(a)\ldots))).}_{\text{$b$ times}} $$ Note that this guarantees that $a+b$ exists; since we also know that successors are unique, it follows that $a+b$ is well-defined.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose there exist $c$ and $c'$ such that $c = a+b$ and $c' = a + b$. Then

$$c' - c = (a+b) - (a+b) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \boxed{c' = c}.$$

If you assume there are two solutions, then they are necessarily equal. Thus there is actually a unique solution.

Comment: Aren't you assuming that (a+b)−(a+b) is unique, also that 0 + c is unique? If so, wouldn't it make the proof circular?

Comment: No. $(a+b) - (a+b)$ doesn't assume anything. I'm just computing over the natural numbers. To be entirely precise, I should have written instead $(a+b) - (a+b) = a+b  - a - b = (a-a) + (b-b)$. Since, indeed, $a=a \Leftrightarrow (a-a) = 0$ (I guess we can take that for granted), and $b=b$, the last part is equal to $0 + 0 = 0$.

Comment: @Paul: If you think about the natural numbers as a subset of the ring of integers, then this subtraction argument works because we know by definition that $(a+b)-(a+b) = 0;$ that's what $-(a+b)$ *is*, it's the number we can add to $a+b$ to get $0,$ the identity element (which we know is unique by standard arguments).

Comment: I would agree that 0 is a unique identity element. I am still not convinced, however, that $c$ is a unique solution to $0 + c$

Comment: "Just computing" already assumes that "$+$" is a map $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N\to\Bbb N$

Comment: @Paul: How are you defining "identity element"?

Comment: @WillR $a*e=a$ where $e$ is the identity element

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: in absence of any precision when it comes to a particular set of axioms, I indeed interpreted "$+$" as its most conventional definition when talking about natural numbers. Now, I recognize the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @Paul: that's right. In our case, that's $a+e=a$ so if you accept $0$ to be an "identity element", why do you disagree with $c+0=c$ ?

Comment: @Paul: So you know that $a+0=a$ by definition of $0.$ Suppose some other element $b$ exists so that $a+0=b.$ Then by symmetry (equality is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)), we have $b=a+0,$ and by transitivity we have $b=a.$

Comment: @WillR Ok, I see now